# Show error if api validation fails using php

Tags: php

```
    if($api_response["success"] === true) {

        header("Location: https://google.com");
        exit;

    } else {
        // print_r($api_response);
        $msg = "Some Error Occured!";
        header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        // echo $msg;
    }
```

In the above code, if true, the code is working perfectly and redirects as expected. But in case it is not true, I want to display error on `index.php`

```
<?php
  if(isset($msg) && $msg != ''){
    echo $msg;
}
?>
```

I am not getting the value of $msg variable when the condition is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send `$msg` in header

```
if($api_response["success"] === true) {
    header("Location: https://google.com");
    exit;
} else {
    $msg = "Some Error Occured!";
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?msg=".$msg);
}
```

and then read your `$msg` like this

```
if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
    print_r($_GET['msg']); 
}
```

> in your case you need to use session to keep private like this

```
if($api_response["success"] === true) {
    header("Location: https://google.com");
    exit;
} else {
    $msg = "Some Error Occured!";
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['msg'] = $msg;
    header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit();
}

//and read like this

<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
 echo $_SESSION['msg'];
 unset($_SESSION['msg']); // remove it now we have used it
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks! but if I send using the GET method, it can be altered, I want it to be immutable.

Comment: so you need to use session to keep private

Comment: @hack3r_0m check now